# How to Concatenate strings conditionally for display in SSRS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

In SSRS, how could I create a field, similar to a "comments" field in a record that would list a set of strings, conditionally, depending on how a set of questions on a VB.NET web form are answered?

Say, 5 questions have RadioButtonLists with "Y", "N", and "N/A" as the three answer items. The answers go into a SQL (Server 2008R2) table as a "Review" record.

Question #2 and #4 are answered "N", the rest are answered "Y" or "N/A."

I'm trying to get that comments field in SSRS to be populated with similar to the following:

```
Q2: 1100 - No Documentation in file.
Q4: 4100 - No Case note.
```

In SQL I've tried declaring a variable to hold a string and concatenating question string values based on field contents. I tried nested IIF expressions in the SSRS column, but I can't figure out how to do what you can do in C# or VB like `string1 = string1 + string2` or `string1 += string2`, in order to selectively add the strings to a variable to then display.

I need an SSRS report for each of the forms and each record needs that comments field listing the "Findings" or questions with "N" answers.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your inputs and expected outputs.  It definitely reads to me like something you tackle in SQL but maybe post the key elements of your current SQL?

Comment: 'll try to simplify.  Say there are 5 questions. 1. Is it Blue  2. Is it Red  3. Is it Yellow  4. Is it Green  5. Is it Orange.  Using the case in my original question, 1 is Y, 2 is N, 3 is Y, 4 is N, and 5 is Y.  Inputs would be the appropriate "Y" or "N" in the appropriate tabel column as would be normal for any data input form.  The SSRS Report displays (or not) the answers to each question. But that's not the important part of the SSRS Report.  (continued...)

Comment: The field I'm asking about is a single "summary" field that would list all of the "N" answers in the format shown in my original question.  That's the "output" if you want to call it that.  See above <pre> block with two lines:  Q2: 1100 - ... and Q4:  4100 - ...  The way that looks above is exactly how I want the "summary" field to look.  One field that lists all of the "N"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments, I think I understand better.  You want a comments column with the No values concatenated together with line breaks.  You will have to adjust the below to match your tables but hopefully this helps.

```
select [AssignedOneActivity], 
       Comments = STUFF( ( 
                                SELECT char(10) + char(13) + a2.[AssignedOneActivity] + ': ' + a2.answer 
                                FROM dbo.[WIA_Youth] a2 
                                where a.ReviewID = a2.ReviewID 
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
                                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
                        ) 
from dbo.[WIA_Youth] a
```

However, I now read that your storing your Q+A in columns.  so maybe this would be better:

```
select
    reviewid,
    Comments =
    case when [AssignedOneActivity] = 'N' then 'Q1: No answers' + char(10) + char(13) else '' end +
    case when [AssignedTwoActivity] = 'N' then 'Q2: No answers' + char(10) + char(13) else '' end +
    case when [AssignedThreeActivity] = 'N' then 'Q3: No answers' + char(10) + char(13) else '' end 
from dbo.wia_youth
```

Comment: Not exactly. I don't want to return a string of text to each question column. So, not Case when Q2 = 'N' then 'No Documentation in file.' else end.  I still want Case when Q2 = 'N' then 'N' or the normal, actual value of the table for each question. 'N' for 'N', 'Y' for 'Y'...  
[Line Break]
I want a list of the 'N's in a separate "commens" field, listing all of questions that were answered no, or 'N'.  That field would look like this if two questions were answered 'N':  
[Line break]
Q2: 1100 - No Documentation in file. [Line break] 
Q4: 4100 - No Case note.[Line break]

Comment: [I cant' get line breaks in this editor to save my life, and they are imperative to demonstrate what I'm looking for]

Comment: Oh I think I follow you.  You want to concatenate the N answers into a comment field... That is possible but a bit costly in SQL.  I will edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse.  I'll give that a try.  It sounds like you understand exactly what I'm asking for.  :-)  Looking at it now, it's a bit complex.  I'll try to figure it out, but I may have to ask questions on the way there.  Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I need your help adjusting it.  All is in a single table.  One question per column.  For each record there's a 'N' or 'Y' or 'N/A' as the answer value...  Below [AssignedOneActivity] is the field name of a question, [WIA_Youth] is the table name, ReviewID is the primary key.  I wasn't susre what to do with "answer" so I commented it out.  I know I haven't adjusted it correctly..."1" ? "2" ? but I got Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max) when I ran it exactly as below:

Comment: select
        [AssignedOneActivity],
        -- Answer,
        Comments =
        STUFF(
            (
            SELECT char(10) + char(13) + a2.[AssignedOneActivity] + ': ' -- + a2.answer
            FROM dbo.[WIA_Youth] a2
            where a.ReviewID = a2.ReviewID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
    from dbo.[WIA_Youth] a

Comment: Hmm.. try the above edit.  I accidentally left out the TYPE parameter in the XML path.

Comment: on the third line, a2.answer... I'm not sure what that should be.  AssignedOneActivity is the question column name and the values would be 'N' or 'Y' or 'N/A'.  I don't have a separate column for questions and answers.  Would I perhaps hard code the text I want included in the summary like this:  + ': ' + 'Q4 - Documentation not entered'  FROM dbo.WIA_Youth a2

Comment: You can remove that if you do not need it.  Or if it is supposed to repeat a particular string you can type it in.  It does not need to be there though.

Comment: No, my quess about "answer" wasn't right.  I only include one question field in my example.  Here, let me add a couple more to make it more like actual use...

Comment: select [AssignedOneActivity], [AssignedBSRemediation], [AssignedWork]
       Comments = STUFF( ( 
                                SELECT char(10) + char(13) + a2.[AssignedOneActivity] + ': ' + a2.Answer
                                FROM dbo.[WIA_Youth] a2 
                                where a.ReviewID = a2.ReviewID 
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
                                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, ''
                        ) 
from dbo.[WIA_Youth] a

Comment: ...and I only want the answers listed if it was a 'N', so there should be a WHERE ????? = 'N'  Oh, this looks like it could be complicated because I guess I'd need a Where AssignedOneActivity = 'N' for that question and a Where AssignedBSRemediation = 'N' for that question, etc. for each question that needs a line entered in the summary field.  It's looking like I'll need a block of query expression for each question.  Doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, add the item to the where clause.  I am lost as to what string you want to end up with in your comments.  Can you create it using the columns in the table?  Something like a2.[AssignedOneActivity] + ': ' + a2.[AssignedBSRemediation] ?

Comment: Sorry for the complexity of this.  I've actually already told the person requesting this be added to the SSRS report that it just can't do it.  I'm willing to stick with that if you thing it's not worth the effort.  None of the actual text string is contained in the database.  All of the text string will have to be hard coded into the query.  The 'N' answers to each question will only be "triggers" as such to indicate which questions will have the text included in the summary.

Comment: For example if [AssignedOneActivity] is 'N' then I need to put into the summary "Q2: Documentation not provided."  No elements of the text string will come from the database. 'N' will just trigger the inclusion of a hard coded string.

Comment: Ok, that helps. So there is like AssignedOneActivity, AssignedTwoActivity etc...?  You would need to build a large case statement and stick that in there.  Case when AssignedOneActivity = 'N' then '1: blah blah blah' when AssignedTwoActivity = 'N' then '2: blah blah blah' ...

Comment: In my messing around I think my original quess about a2.answer was correct.  That would be where the hard coded text would go, I believe.  With a single question in the query I got a comments field containing the text I hard coded in place of a2.answer.

Comment: Yes, with the large case statement... that sounds about right.  and yes, there are like 50 questions, AssignedOneActivity, AssignedBSRemediation, AssignedWork, MetCriteria, DocumentationProvided, etc.

Comment: That is helpful, I thought the table was normalized... I changed my answer now that it is more clear.  See the 2nd code part.

Comment: Jesse, thank you so much for being so patient with me and sticking with this.  So, it looks like I ONLY need the CASE WHEN and not the XML PATH at all?  Is that right?  If that's the case, this won't be so horribly complicated after all.  :-)  They are constantly adding questions and removing questions so it's kind of a bear to maintain.  So the simpler the solution the better.  Thank you again, so much, for helping me with this.  I just didn't think it was doable.  :-D

Comment: Yes, just the case statement.  Really what would help is to redesign the tables but that might not be possible.  If you had a table with ReviewID, QuestionID, Answer you wouldn't have to work much at all when a question was added.  but i know that is a larger project.

Comment: Oh, no.  I was just in too big a hurry and didn't plug in a couple of the real column names.  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I know what you're saying about having QuestionID, Answer in a table, but I'm not sure that would work for our process.  We have, like, "auditors" who "review" a client case in our files and answer all these questions based on thier findings.  So, there's 60 to 80 questions for each record or "review" (ReviewID PK).  After all these questions are answered the report in SSRS just lists the answers for each question/column.  60 questions = 60 columns.  *Some* of the questions are particularly important and they want a summary of the ones with "failing" answers.

Comment: Oh, thank you again.  That CASE WHEN looks like it will do the trick.  It gave me a nice list of "No" answers/text for each 'N' just where it should.  Once I plug it into SSRS those new line characters should format it nicely.

Comment: I added about 40 CASE WHEN questions to the SSRS report and it works great!  Exactly how I had hoped.  Thank you again, very much!

Comment: Great, glad it worked out.  Would you mind marking this as the answer so people know it is closed out?